# Could anyone prove why O(n^(log n)) < O((log n)^n)?

Tags: algorithms

Could someone provide a rigorous proof of why $O(n^{log n}) \leq O((\log n)^n)$ is true? I'm trying to do this by induction but it isn't working. Thanks.

Comment: Compare the logarithms of these two functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using $ < $ with the big-oh notation is a bit of abuse of notation.
Formally, I take your statement to mean $\forall f(n) \in O(n^{\log n}), \; f(n) \in O((\log n)^n)$.

Let $f(n) \in O(n^{\log n})$, by definition of big-oh we know that the function is eventually bounded from above by $c n^{\log n}$ for some constant $c > 0$.
Then, for sufficiently large $n$,
$$
f(n) \le c n^{\log n} = c 2^{\log(n^{\log n})} = c2^{\log^2 n} < c2^n < c (\log n)^n,
$$
showing that $f(n) \in O((\log n)^n)$.

In particular the constant c in the last term can be made arbitrarily small. Indeed $n^{\log n} \in o((\log n)^n)$. A simple way to see this is by taking the limit of the ratio of the two functions:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^{\log n}}{(\log n)^n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{\log^2 n}}{2^{n \log n}} =
2^{\lim_{n \to \infty} \log^2 n - n \log n} = 0
$$

Comment: +1 for mentioning the ambiguity of $<$.

Answer (score -5):

Try to check for large values of n 
Suppose n = 1000 and base of log = 10.
i.e 
for n^(logn) = (1000)^3 = 1000000000
(logn)^n     = (3)^100  = 5.1537752e+47

Thus results are speaking for itself.

Comment: That is not a rigorous proof.

Comment: That's not a rigorous proof, but it shows intuitively that it might be true. It could be the first step of such a way of thought. This example accompanied by limits would be quite better.